# How to align text at the bottom in SwiftUI

Tags: layout, swiftui, alignment

My code is as bellow:

```
struct DotView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            let width = geo.size.width
            HStack() {
                VStack() {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: width, height: width)
                    Spacer()
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: width, height: width)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}


struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text("09")
            DotView()
                .frame(width: 7, height: 30, alignment: .center)
            Text("22")
            Text("PM")
                .font(.system(size: 20))
        }
        .font(.system(size: 66, weight: .medium))
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

The result is as bellow pic, all the view is align at the center.

[image: Text]

How to make the "pm" align "09" and "22" at the bottom such as bellow pic?

[image: Text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VStack with Spacer() and set frame for HStack()

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text("09")
            DotView()
                .frame(width: 7, height: 30, alignment: .center)
            Text("22")
            VStack { // Added VStack with Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Text("PM")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 55) // Added Line, adjust frame of HStack
        .font(.system(size: 66, weight: .medium))
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just found that you can use `HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline)` or `.firstTextBaseLine`.

```
HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) {
    Text("09")
    DotView()
        .frame(width: 7, height: 30, alignment: .center)
    Text("22")
    VStack { // Added VStack with Spacer()
    Spacer()
    Text("PM")
        .font(.system(size: 20))
 }
```